# What is Google Material Design for Landscape Tablet Navigation? (NavBar)

Tags: android, material-design, tablet

Working on re-designing an application that is Android and is used in Landscape mode.

Want to be able to have the user 1 click to navigate.

It currently has tabs on the left side (basically a bottom nav bar on the left)

Can't find resources that say anything about navigation bar on Tablet Landscape mode.

Anyone have creative ideas or examples of how people do it?

Thanks!

Comment: might be better off asking on the UX forum

Comment: Bottom Navigation or Navigation Drawer.